# How to override kops' default kube-dns add-on spec

Tags: kubernetes, kops

We're running kops->terraform k8s clusters in AWS, and because of the number of k8s jobs we have in flight at once, the kube-dns container is getting OOMkilled, forcing us to raise the memory limit.

As for automating this so it both survives cluster upgrades and is automatically done for new clusters created from the same template, I don't see a way to override the canned kops spec.  The only options I can see involve some update (`kubectl edit deployment kube-dns`, delete the kube-dns add-on deployment and use our own, overwrite the spec uploaded to the kops state store, etc.) that probably needs to be done each time after using kops to update the cluster.

I've checked the docs and even the spec source and no other options stand out.  Is there a way to pass a custom kube-dns deployment spec to kops?  Or tell it not to install the kube-dns add-on?

Comment: If you have not yet tried it, applying a [horizontal pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to distribute the load across several `kube-dns` Pods may help that problem

Comment: _Or tell it not to install the kube-dns add-on_ You almost certainly do not want do that, unless you mean by replacing it with CoreDNS; without `kube-dns`, a spectacular number of things will break